# How to cache resources in SolidJS

Tags: caching, solid-js

How can I cache server responses in SolidJS? For example, I have this code in '/routes/users/index.tsx'

```js
export default () => {
  const [users] = createResource(getUsers);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Users list</h1>

      <ul>
        <For each={users()}>
          {(user) => <A href={`/users/${user.id}`}>{user.name}</A>}
        </For>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
```

And this code in '/routes/users/[id].tsx'

```js
export default () => {
  const params = useParams();
  const [users] = createResource(getUsers);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>User {params.id}</div>

      <h2>See all users</h2>
      <ul>
        <For each={users()}>{(user) => <li>{user.name}</li>}</For>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

In this case, I will be making a request to the server every time I switch between the pages '/users' and '/users/:id'.

I found a solution to  this problem:
You can extract all your resources into a separate file, for example, '/api/users.api.ts'.

```js
export const [usersResource, usersResourceAction] = createResource(getUsers);
```

Then, your pages will look like this:
'/routes/users/[id].tsx':

```js
export default () => {
  const params = useParams();
  return (
    <div>
      <div>User {params.id}</div>

      <h2>See all users</h2>
      <ul>
        <For each={usersResource()}>{(user) => <li>{user.name}</li>}</For>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

'/routes/users/index.tsx':

```js
export default () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Users list</h1>

      <ul>
        <For each={usersResource()}>
          {(user) => <A href={`/users/${user.id}`}>{user.name}</A>}
        </For>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

With this approach, I will only make one request during the initialization of the application, and I can also manage refetching inside the '/api/users.api.ts' file.

```js
export async function addUser(name: string) {
  const body = JSON.stringify({
    name,
  });
  const req = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/users", {
    method: "POST",
    body,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
  if (req.ok) {
    usersResourceAction.refetch()
  }
  return req.json();
}
```

However, this approach does not allow me to make resources with signals inside the '/api/users.api.ts' file."

```js
const params = useParams(); // incorrect - we can't use useParams outside of component
export const [getUserById, getUserByIdActions] = createResource(params.id, getOneUser);
```

I also found the library **'solid-cache'**, but it doesn't have the ability to update individual keys (for example, update the 'users' key when creating a new user)

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in caching mechanism since the resource expect you to return a promise. It would not make sense anyway because you don't hit an API endpoint directly but throught a wrapper. You can implement your own if you like.